# How to reduce player health on a player health bar in a scrolling map game?

Tags: python, pygame

I have been having a problem with my code in python, I am using the modules pygame, random, and math. I cannot seem to be able to reduce one of my player's health on a player health bar. The player health bar is fixed to the x and y positions of the specified player, and is not reducing the player health when shot by the other player.

I have already tried searching the internet for answers, but I have found none.

```
import OpenGL
import panda3d
import pygame
import pyglet
import tkinter
import time
import random
import math

pygame.init()
display_width = 1250
display_height = 650
map_width = display_width*3
map_height = display_height*3

green = (0, 255, 0)
yellow = (255, 255, 0)
black = (0, 0, 0)
white = (255, 255, 255)
red = (255, 0, 0)
blue = (0, 0, 255)

person_height = 113
person_width = 171
person2_width = 171
person2_height = 113


gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width, display_height))
pygame.display.set_caption('Wert')
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

personImg = pygame.image.load('Untitled7.png').convert_alpha()
personImg2 = pygame.image.load('Untitled8.png').convert_alpha()
bulletImg = pygame.image.load('Untitled9.png').convert_alpha()
background = pygame.image.load('Untitled4.png')

player_health = 100
player2_health = 100
x = map_width/2
y = map_height/2 - 56.5
ny = map_height/2 + 56.5
nx = map_width/2
#x = (0)
#y = (display_height * 0.37)
#ny = (display_height * 0.37)
#nx = (display_width * 0.87)
#thing_width = 100
#thing_height = 100
bullets1 = pygame.sprite.Group()





class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.original_image = personImg
        self.image = self.original_image.copy()
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=(person_width/2, person_height/2))
        self.angle = 0
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y
        self.player_health = 100
        self.x_change = 0
        self.y_change = 0




    def update(self):
        self.x_change = 0
        self.y_change = 0
        keystate = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keystate[pygame.K_w] and pygame.key.get_mods() and pygame.KMOD_LSHIFT and not pygame.sprite.collide_rect(self, player2): #and not pygame.Rect.collidepoint(self.rect, player2.rect.x + person2_width / 2, player2.rect.y + person2_height) and not pygame.Rect.collidepoint(self.rect, player2.rect.x + person2_width / 4, player2.rect.y + person2_height) and not pygame.Rect.collidepoint(self.rect, player2.rect.x + person2_width - 10, player2.rect.y + person2_height) and not pygame.Rect.collidepoint(self.rect, player2.rect.x + person2_width/2, player2.rect.y) and not pygame.Rect.collidepoint(self.rect, player2.rect.x + person2_width/4, player2.rect.y) and not pygame.Rect.collidepoint(self.rect, player2.rect.x + person2_width - 10, player2.rect.y) and not pygame.Rect.collidepoint(self.rect, player2.rect.x, player2.rect.y + person2_height/2) and not pygame.Rect.collidepoint(self.rect, player2.rect.x, player2.rect.y + person2_height/4) and not pygame.Rect.collidepoint(self.rect, player2.rect.x, player2.rect.y + person2_height - 10) and not pygame.Rect.collidepoint(self.rect, player2.rect.x + person2_width, player2.rect.y + person2_height/2) and not pygame.Rect.collidepoint(self.rect, player2.rect.x + person2_width, player2.rect.y + person2_height/4) and not pygame.Rect.collidepoint(self.rect, player2.rect.x + person2_width, player2.rect.y + person2_height - 10):
            self.rect.x += math.cos(math.radians(self.angle)) * 10
            self.rect.y += math.sin(math.radians(self.angle)) * -10
        elif keystate[pygame.K_w] and not pygame.sprite.collide_rect(self, player2): #and not pygame.Rect.collidepoint(self.rect, player2.rect.x + person2_width/2, player2.rect.y + person2_height) and not pygame.Rect.collidepoint(self.rect, player2.rect.x + person2_width/4, player2.rect.y + person2_height) and not pygame.Rect.collidepoint(self.rect, player2.rect.x + person2_width - 10, player2.rect.y + person2_height) and not pygame.Rect.collidepoint(self.rect, player2.rect.x + person2_width/2, player2.rect.y) and not pygame.Rect.collidepoint(self.rect, player2.rect.x + person2_width/4, player2.rect.y) and not pygame.Rect.collidepoint(self.rect, player2.rect.x + person2_width - 10, player2.rect.y) and not pygame.Rect.collidepoint(self.rect, player2.rect.x, player2.rect.y + person2_height/2) and not pygame.Rect.collidepoint(self.rect, player2.rect.x, player2.rect.y + person2_height/4) and not pygame.Rect.collidepoint(self.rect, player2.rect.x, player2.rect.y + person2_height - 10) and not pygame.Rect.collidepoint(self.rect, player2.rect.x + person2_width, player2.rect.y + person2_height/2) and not pygame.Rect.collidepoint(self.rect, player2.rect.x + person2_width, player2.rect.y + person2_height/4) and not pygame.Rect.collidepoint(self.rect, player2.rect.x + person2_width, player2.rect.y + person2_height - 10):
            self.rect.x += math.cos(math.radians(self.angle)) * 5
            self.rect.y += math.sin(math.radians(self.angle)) * -5
        if keystate[pygame.K_s] and not pygame.sprite.collide_rect(self, player2): #and not pygame.Rect.collidepoint(self.rect, player2.rect.x + person2_width/2, player2.rect.y) and not pygame.Rect.collidepoint(self.rect, player2.rect.x + person2_width/4, player2.rect.y) and not pygame.Rect.collidepoint(self.rect, player2.rect.x + person2_width - 10, player2.rect.y) and not pygame.Rect.collidepoint(self.rect, player2.rect.x + person2_width/2, player2.rect.y + person2_height) and not pygame.Rect.collidepoint(self.rect, player2.rect.x + person2_width/4, player2.rect.y + person2_height) and not pygame.Rect.collidepoint(self.rect, player2.rect.x + person2_width - 10, player2.rect.y + person2_height) and not pygame.Rect.collidepoint(self.rect, player2.rect.x, player2.rect.y + person2_height/2) and not pygame.Rect.collidepoint(self.rect, player2.rect.x, player2.rect.y + person2_height/4) and not pygame.Rect.collidepoint(self.rect, player2.rect.x, player2.rect.y + person2_height - 10) and not pygame.Rect.collidepoint(self.rect, player2.rect.x + person2_width, player2.rect.y + person2_height/2) and not pygame.Rect.collidepoint(self.rect, player2.rect.x + person2_width, player2.rect.y + person2_height/4) and not pygame.Rect.collidepoint(self.rect, player2.rect.x + person2_width, player2.rect.y + person2_height - 10):
            self.rect.x += math.cos(math.radians(self.angle)) * -5
            self.rect.y += math.sin(math.radians(self.angle)) * 5
        if pygame.sprite.collide_rect(self, player2):
            self.x_change += 7
            self.y_change += 7
        #if keystate[pygame.K_d] and pygame.key.get_mods() and pygame.KMOD_LSHIFT and not pygame.Rect.collidepoint(self.rect, player2.rect.x, player2.rect.y + person2_height/2) and not pygame.Rect.collidepoint(self.rect, player2.rect.x, player2.rect.y + person2_height/4) and not pygame.Rect.collidepoint(self.rect, player2.rect.x, player2.rect.y + person2_height - 10):
            #self.x_change = 10
        #elif keystate[pygame.K_d] and not pygame.Rect.collidepoint(self.rect, player2.rect.x, player2.rect.y + person2_height/2) and not pygame.Rect.collidepoint(self.rect, player2.rect.x, player2.rect.y + person2_height/4) and not pygame.Rect.collidepoint(self.rect, player2.rect.x, player2.rect.y + person2_height - 10):
            #self.x_change = 5
        #if keystate[pygame.K_a] and not pygame.Rect.collidepoint(self.rect, player2.rect.x + person2_width, player2.rect.y + person2_height/2) and not pygame.Rect.collidepoint(self.rect, player2.rect.x + person2_width, player2.rect.y + person2_height/4) and not pygame.Rect.collidepoint(self.rect, player2.rect.x + person2_width, player2.rect.y + person2_height - 10):
            #self.x_change = -5
        self.rect.x += self.x_change
        self.rect.y += self.y_change
        if self.rect.right > map_width:
            self.rect.right = map_width
        if self.rect.left < 0:
            self.rect.left = 0
        if self.rect.top < 0:
            self.rect.top = 0
        if self.rect.bottom > map_height:
            self.rect.bottom = map_height
        self.rect.contains(healthbar1.rect)
        self.image.blit(healthbar1.image, (self.rect.x, self.rect.y))
        healthbar1.rect.clamp_ip(self.rect)



    def shoot(self):
        bullet = Bullet1(self.rect.x, self.rect.y)
        all_sprites.add(bullet)
        bullets.add(bullet)

    def modifyRotation(self):
        self.angle += 5

    def modifyRotation1(self):
        self.angle += -5

    def getRotation(self):
        return self.angle

    def getRotation1(self):
        return self.angle

class Healthbar1(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        player_health = 100
        for bullet1 in bullets1:
            if pygame.sprite.collide_rect(bullet1, player):
                bullet1.kill()
                player_health -= 5
                break
        if player_health == 0 or player_health <= 0:
            died()
        if player_health > 75:
            player_health_color = green
        elif player_health > 50:
            player_health_color = yellow
        else:
            player_health_color = red
        self.image = pygame.Surface((player_health, 25))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.image.fill(player_health_color)


class Combined(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.rect = player.rect
        self.rect.contains(healthbar1.rect)
        self.image = player.image
        self.image.blit(healthbar1.image, (player.rect.x, player.rect.y))



class Player2(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.original_image = personImg2
        self.image = self.original_image.copy()
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=(person2_width / 2, person2_height / 2))
        self.angle = 0
        self.rect.x = nx
        self.rect.y = ny
        self.player2_health = 100
        self.x_change1 = 0
        self.y_change1 = 0

    def update(self):
        self.x_change1 = 0
        self.y_change1 = 0
        keystate = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keystate[pygame.K_UP] and pygame.key.get_mods() and pygame.KMOD_RSHIFT and not pygame.sprite.collide_rect(self, player): #and not pygame.Rect.collidepoint(self.rect, player.rect.x + person_width/2, player.rect.y + person_height) and not pygame.Rect.collidepoint(self.rect, player.rect.x + person_width/4, player.rect.y + person_height) and not pygame.Rect.collidepoint(self.rect, player.rect.x + person_width - 10, player.rect.y + person_height):
            self.rect.x += math.cos(math.radians(self.angle)) * -10
            self.rect.y += math.sin(math.radians(self.angle)) * 10
        elif keystate[pygame.K_UP] and not pygame.sprite.collide_rect(self, player): #and not pygame.Rect.collidepoint(self.rect, player.rect.x + person_width/2, player.rect.y + person_height) and not pygame.Rect.collidepoint(self.rect, player.rect.x + person_width/4, player.rect.y + person_height) and not pygame.Rect.collidepoint(self.rect, player.rect.x + person_width - 10, player.rect.y + person_height):
            self.rect.x += math.cos(math.radians(self.angle)) * -5
            self.rect.y += math.sin(math.radians(self.angle)) * 5
        if keystate[pygame.K_DOWN] and not pygame.sprite.collide_rect(self, player): #and not pygame.Rect.collidepoint(self.rect, player.rect.x + person_width/2, player.rect.y) and not pygame.Rect.collidepoint(self.rect, player.rect.x + person_width/4, player.rect.y) and not pygame.Rect.collidepoint(self.rect, player.rect.x + person_width - 10, player.rect.y):
            self.rect.x += math.cos(math.radians(self.angle)) * 5
            self.rect.y += math.sin(math.radians(self.angle)) * -5
        if pygame.sprite.collide_rect(self, player):
            self.x_change1 += -7
            self.y_change1 += -7
        #if keystate[pygame.K_LEFT] and pygame.key.get_mods() and pygame.KMOD_RSHIFT and not pygame.Rect.collidepoint(self.rect, player.rect.x + person_width, player.rect.y + person_height/2) and not pygame.Rect.collidepoint(self.rect, player.rect.x + person_width, player.rect.y + person_height/4) and not pygame.Rect.collidepoint(self.rect, player.rect.x + person_width, player.rect.y + person_height - 10):
            #self.x_change1 = -10
        #elif keystate[pygame.K_LEFT] and not pygame.Rect.collidepoint(self.rect, player.rect.x + person_width, player.rect.y + person_height/2) and not pygame.Rect.collidepoint(self.rect, player.rect.x + person_width, player.rect.y + person_height/4) and not pygame.Rect.collidepoint(self.rect, player.rect.x + person_width, player.rect.y + person_height - 10):
            #self.x_change1 = -5
        #if keystate[pygame.K_RIGHT] and not pygame.Rect.collidepoint(self.rect, player.rect.x, player.rect.y + person_height/2) and not pygame.Rect.collidepoint(self.rect, player.rect.x, player.rect.y + person_height/4) and not pygame.Rect.collidepoint(self.rect, player.rect.x, player.rect.y + person_height - 10):
            #self.x_change1 = 5
        self.rect.x += self.x_change1
        self.rect.y += self.y_change1
        if self.rect.right > map_width:
            self.rect.right = map_width
        if self.rect.left < 0:
            self.rect.left = 0
        if self.rect.top < 0:
            self.rect.top = 0
        if self.rect.bottom > map_height:
            self.rect.bottom = map_height

    def shoot(self):
        bullet = Bullet(self.rect.x, self.rect.y)
        all_sprites.add(bullet)
        bullets1.add(bullet)

    def modifyRotation(self):
        self.angle += 5

    def modifyRotation1(self):
        self.angle += -5

    def getRotation(self):
        return self.angle

    def getRotation1(self):
        return self.angle

all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
player = Player()
player2 = Player2()
healthbar1 = Healthbar1()
combined = Combined()
#all_sprites.add(combined)
all_sprites.add(healthbar1)
bullets = pygame.sprite.Group()
bullets1 = pygame.sprite.Group()

class Bullet(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.Surface((20, 10))
        self.mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(gameDisplay)
        self.image.fill(black)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y



    def update(self):
        #point = pygame.math.Vector2D(player.rect.x, player.rect.y + person_height/2)
        #point1 = pygame.math.Vector2D(player.rect.x + person_width, player.rect.y + person_height/2)
        #vector = point1 - point
        #self.rect.x += vector
        #self.rect.y += vector
        #self.rect.x += self.x_change
        #self.rect.y += self.y_change
        if self.rect.left > map_width:
            self.kill()
        if self.rect.right < 0:
            self.kill()
        for angle in [0, 30, 45, 60, 0 + 90, 30 + 90, 45 + 90, 60 + 90, 0 + 180, 30 + 180, 45 + 180, 60 + 180, 0 + 270,
                      30 + 270, 45 + 270, 60 + 270]:
            bullet_speed = 5

            self.rect.x += -bullet_speed * math.cos(math.radians(player2.angle))
            self.rect.y += bullet_speed * math.sin(math.radians(player2.angle))



class Bullet1(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.Surface((20, 10))
        self.mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(gameDisplay)
        self.image.fill(black)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y


    def update(self):
        if self.rect.left > map_width:
            self.kill()
        if self.rect.right < 0:
            self.kill()
        for angle in [0, 30, 45, 60, 0 + 90, 30 + 90, 45 + 90, 60 + 90, 0 + 180, 30 + 180, 45 + 180, 60 + 180, 0 + 270,
                      30 + 270, 45 + 270, 60 + 270]:
            bullet_speed1 = 5

            self.rect.x += bullet_speed1 * math.cos(math.radians(player.angle))
            self.rect.y += -bullet_speed1 * math.sin(math.radians(player.angle))


class Map(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, map_width, map_height):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = background
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(0, 0, map_width, map_height)
        self.width = map_width
        self.height = map_height

class Camera(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, display_height, display_width):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.Surface((display_width, display_height))
        self.camera = pygame.Rect(0, 0, display_width, display_height)
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(0, 0, display_width, display_height)
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y
        self.width = display_width
        self.height = display_height

    def apply(self, entity):
        return entity.rect.move(self.camera.topleft)


    def update(self):
        x = (-player.rect.x + -player2.rect.x)/2 + int(display_width/2)
        y = (-player.rect.y + -player2.rect.y)/2 + int(display_height/2)
        self.camera = pygame.Rect(x, y, self.width, self.height)


bullets = pygame.sprite.Group()
players1 = pygame.sprite.Group()
players2 = pygame.sprite.Group()
bullet1 = Bullet1(x, y)
players1.add(player)
players2.add(player2)
map = Map(map_width, map_height)
camera = Camera(display_height, display_width)
bullet = Bullet(x, y)
all_sprites.add(player)
all_sprites.add(player2)

def button(msg,x,y,w,h,ic,ac,action=None):
    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
    if x+w > mouse[0] > x and y+h > mouse[1] > y:
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, ac,(x,y,w,h))

        if click[0] == 1 and action != None:
            action()
    else:
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, ic,(x,y,w,h))

    smallText = pygame.font.SysFont("timesnewromanms",20)
    textSurf, textRect = text_objects(msg, smallText)
    textRect.center = ( (x+(w/2)), (y+(h/2)) )
    gameDisplay.blit(textSurf, textRect)

def died():

    GameOver = True

    while GameOver:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

        gameDisplay.fill(white)
        redrawgame()
        largeText = pygame.font.SysFont("timesnewromanms", 115)
        TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects("Player 2 wins", largeText)
        TextRect.center = ((display_width / 2), (display_height / 2))
        gameDisplay.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)

        button("Play Again", 500, 400, 100, 50, blue, blue, game_loop)
        button("Quit", 700, 400, 100, 50, red, red, quitgame)

        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(15)

def died1():


    GameOver = True

    while GameOver:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

        gameDisplay.fill(white)
        redrawgame()
        largeText = pygame.font.SysFont("timesnewromanms", 115)
        TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects("Player 1 wins", largeText)
        TextRect.center = ((display_width / 2), (display_height / 2))
        gameDisplay.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)

        button("Play Again", 500, 400, 100, 50, blue, blue, game_loop)
        button("Quit", 700, 400, 100, 50, red, red, quitgame)

        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(15)

def newRotate():
    keystate = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keystate[pygame.K_a]:
        player.modifyRotation()
        player.image = player.original_image.copy()
        player.image = pygame.transform.rotate(player.image, player.getRotation())
        player.rect = player.image.get_rect(center=player.rect.center)
    elif keystate[pygame.K_d]:
        player.modifyRotation1()
        player.image = player.original_image.copy()
        player.image = pygame.transform.rotate(player.image, player.getRotation1())
        player.rect = player.image.get_rect(center=player.rect.center)
    if keystate[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        player2.modifyRotation()
        player2.image = player2.original_image.copy()
        player2.image = pygame.transform.rotate(player2.image, player2.getRotation())
        player2.rect = player2.image.get_rect(center=player2.rect.center)
    elif keystate[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        player2.modifyRotation1()
        player2.image = player2.original_image.copy()
        player2.image = pygame.transform.rotate(player2.image, player2.getRotation1())
        player2.rect = player2.image.get_rect(center=player2.rect.center)



def redrawgame():
    player.angle = 0
    player2.angle = 0
    player.rect.x = x
    player.rect.y = y
    player2.rect.x = nx
    player2.rect.y = ny


def quitgame():
    pygame.quit()
    quit()
def text_objects(text, font):
    textSurface = font.render(text, True, black)
    return textSurface, textSurface.get_rect()

def game_loop():
    x = (0)
    y = (display_height * 0.37)
    ny = (display_height * 0.37)
    nx = (display_width * 0.87)
    y_change = 0
    x_change = 0
    x_change1 = 0
    y_change1 = 0
    bullet1 = Bullet1(x, y)
    bullet = Bullet(x, y)
    #thing_startx = display_width/2
    #thing_starty = display_height/2
    #thing_startx1 = display_width / 2 - thing_width
    #thing_starty1 = display_height / 2 - thing_height
    #thing_startx2 = display_width / 2 + thing_width + 50
    #thing_starty2 = display_height / 2 + 50
    #thing_startx3 = display_width - 500
    #thing_starty3 = display_height - 450
    #thing_startx4 = display_width - 950
    #thing_starty4 = display_height - 350
    #thing_startx5 = display_width - 800
    #thing_starty5 = display_height - 250



    gameExit = False

    player_health = 100
    player2_health = 100

    for bullet in bullets:
        bullet.kill()
    for bullet in bullets1:
        bullet.kill()

    while not gameExit:

            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    pygame.quit()
                    quit()
                keystate = pygame.key.get_pressed()
                keystate1 = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
                if keystate[pygame.K_SPACE]:
                    player.shoot()
                if keystate1[2]:
                    player2.shoot()




            y += y_change
            x += x_change
            ny += y_change1
            nx += x_change1



            gameDisplay.fill(white)
            #block = pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, black, (thing_startx, thing_starty, thing_width, thing_height))
            #block1 = pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, black, (thing_startx1, thing_starty1, thing_width, thing_height))
            #block2 = pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, black, (thing_startx2, thing_starty2, thing_width, thing_height))
            #block3 = pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, black, (thing_startx3, thing_starty3, thing_width, thing_height))
            #block4 = pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, black, (thing_startx4, thing_starty4, thing_width, thing_height))
            #block5 = pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, black, (thing_startx5, thing_starty5, thing_width, thing_height))

            #block
            #block1
            #block2
            #block3
            #block4
            #block5


            player
            player2

            Camera(map_width, map_height)



            #if x > thing_startx and x < thing_startx + thing_width or x + person_width > thing_startx and x + person_width < thing_startx + thing_width:
                #hit()

            #if thing_starty > display_height:
                #thing_starty = 0 - thing_height
                #thing_startx = random.randrange(0, display_width)

            #if pygame.Rect.colliderect(block, bullet) or pygame.Rect.colliderect(block1, bullet) or pygame.Rect.colliderect(block2, bullet) or pygame.Rect.colliderect(block3, bullet) or pygame.Rect.colliderect(block4, bullet) or pygame.Rect.colliderect(block5, bullet):
                #bullet.kill()
            #if pygame.Rect.colliderect(block, bullet1) or pygame.Rect.colliderect(block1, bullet1) or pygame.Rect.colliderect(block2, bullet1) or pygame.Rect.colliderect(block3, bullet1) or pygame.Rect.colliderect(block4, bullet1) or pygame.Rect.colliderect(block5, bullet1):
                #bullet1.kill()





            for bullet1 in bullets1:
                if pygame.sprite.collide_rect(bullet1, player):
                    bullet1.kill()
                    player_health -= 5
                    break
            if player_health == 0 or player_health <= 0:
                died()

            for bullet in bullets:
                if pygame.sprite.collide_rect(bullet, player2):
                    bullet.kill()
                    player2_health -= 5
                    break
            if player2_health == 0 or player2_health <= 0:
                died1()

            #zombie.move_towards_player(player)
            #zombie1.move_towards_player(player)
            #zombie2.move_towards_player2(player2)
            #zombie3.move_towards_player2(player2)



            newRotate()

            all_sprites.update()
            camera.update()





            gameDisplay.blit(background, (0,0))
            for sprite in all_sprites:
                gameDisplay.blit(sprite.image, camera.apply(sprite))
            #all_sprites.draw(gameDisplay)

            pygame.display.flip()
            pygame.display.update()
            clock.tick(60)


game_loop()
pygame.quit()
quit()
```

Comment: You can create a rect that adjusts it's horizontal length according to how much damage has been taken.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here. It's hard to help you if you just copy paste your source code, we need a specific problem, minimal code, and both actual and desired output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `HealthBar` class only computes it's position *once* during the `__init__()`, so it will never update.

Perhaps it needs an `update()` function to regenerate it?

```
class Healthbar1(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.player_health = 100
        self.drawn_health  = 0 # don't regenerate unless it's changed
        self.update()     # generate the first bar

    def change(self, new_health):
        self.player_health = new_health

    def update(self):
        # DO THIS ALL SOMEWHERE ELSE, IT'S NOT PART OF A HEALTH-BAR
        #for bullet1 in bullets1:
        #    if pygame.sprite.collide_rect(bullet1, player):
        #        bullet1.kill()
        #        player_health -= 5
        #        break
        #if player_health == 0 or player_health <= 0:
        #    died()

        # Only re-make the bar if it's different from last time
        if self.player_health != self.drawn_health:
            if self.player_health > 75:
                player_health_color = green
            elif self.player_health > 50:
                player_health_color = yellow
            else:
                player_health_color = red
            self.image = pygame.Surface((self.player_health, 25))
            self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
            self.image.fill(player_health_color)
            self.drawn_health = self.player_health
```